# Why is field referencing not allowed in an enum (or is this a compiler bug?)

Tags: c#, enums, mono

When I use the following code:

```
using System;

namespace Foo {

    [Flags]
    public enum Bar : ulong {
        None          = 0x0000000000000000,
        A             = 0x8000000000000000,
        B             = 0x0000000000000001L | A,
        C             = 0x0000000000000002L | B,
        D             = 0x0000000000000004L | A,
        All           = A | B | C | D
    }
}
```

The mono compiler crashes. Is this due to a semantical error (something that is not allowed in the language), but is unnoticed by the compiler or is this a compiler-bug?

Version: Mono 2.10.8.1

I've filed a bug report at bugzilla (https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=15801)

Comment: All right, what is wrong with this question? I don't see why this is downvoted? I provide a MWE...

Comment: It compiles just fine in VS2012, so I would say it's a mono compiler issue.

Comment: Does it compile and is correct?

Comment: When using the mono (mcs) compiler the compiler throws a NumberFormatException and prints a trace (not the resulting program (there is no file output), but the compiler). It seems to throw an exception in the codegen part. I just want to make sure such structures are allowed...

Comment: I'm surprised that's valid C#. However, that's grounds for an upvote IMO, not a downvote, as it's taught me something new.

Comment: What happens when you use ulong suffixes with your literals instead of the long suffixes, i.e. `0x0000000000000001UL`?

Comment: I'm rather amazed it builds too.  Kind'a neat.  It appears to work in mono here (http://www.compileonline.com/compile_csharp_online.php) mono v2.10.2.0

Comment: @hatchet: the same error: the error is caused by Block.Emit (I suppose that's the codegen) that calls `UInt64.System.IConvertible.ToInt64` and then causes a Number overflow... Mono 2.10.8.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the C# language spec, section 14.3:

> The associated value of an enum member may not, directly or indirectly, use the value of its own associated enum member. Other than this circularity restriction, enum member initializers may freely refer to other enum member initializers, regardless of their textual position.

So your code should be correct (as it has already been suggested in the comments), and thus it should be a compiler bug.